# Rails, get the value of link_to or detect which a href was clicked wo adding it to url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, href, parameters, link-to

I have the list of ids and the links to the next page for every id.

```
    <% 
    ids.each do |p|     
    %>
    <a href="<%= show_patient_tables_hospitals_path %>"><%= p.mk1 %></a>    
    <%end%>
```

I want to store in the cookies what id was clicked (chosen for the next page). So, I came up with such an idea:

```
    <% 
    ids.each do |p|     
    %>
   <a href="<%= show_patient_tables_hospitals_path %>"><%= p.mk1 %> <%=cookies[:pat_id]%></a> 
   <%end%>
```

This idea is bad, because the last id will be saved in the cookies and not the one that was clicked. So I tried to do something like this:

```
<% 
ids.each do |p|     
%>
   <%= link_to p.mk1, show_patient_tables_hospitals_path, :id => p.mk1 %></li> 
<%end%>
```

And I tried to catch params[:id] in the controller:

```
logger.info("#### show patient params #{params}") 
{"action"=>"show_patient_tables", "controller"=>"hospitals", "locale"=>"en"}
```

Somehow it does not send the params[:id].

Do you have any idea how I can detect which id was clicked on, so that I can catch it in the controller? 
(**Note**: I do not want id to appear in the url!!! So, I dont want sth like this `<a href="<%= show_patient_tables_hospitals_path/<%=p.mk1 %>`

Thanks in advance.

Katja

edit:
routes:

```
get '/hospitalDB/show_patient_tables' => 'hospitals#show_patient_tables'
```

in a hospitals_controller:

```
def show_patient_tables
 logger.info("#### show patient params #{params}") 
 id=params[:id]
end
```

Comment: I think you'd be better using Javascript to attain the `id` of the image, and then we can work with [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to handle storing that in the cookies / session

Comment: @RichPeck could you provide just a small example? I am really bad at Javascript.

Comment: Sure, let me just have some dinner & I'll put something down!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your "next page" is always the same (you don't change the link_to based on the ID), I'd try something like this:

---

```
<%= link_to p.mk1, show_patient_tables_hospitals_path, :id => p.mk1, :class => "demo" %>

$(".demo").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/session",
        data: {id: $(this).attr("id")},
        success: function(data) {
            document.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert("Sorry, there was an error!");
        }
    });
});

#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
def session
    session[:next_id] = params[:id]
end

#app/config/routes.rb
get 'session' => 'application#session'
```

---

This will basically send your request to a `session` action in a controller, allowing you to set a session variable for your ID. After this has been done, you'll be able to redirect to the page with Ajax, and use the session variable to modify the content

Comment: by changing "/session" to "/show_patient_tables" it shows me all the time "Sorry, there was an error"

Comment: Firstly, where does "/show_patient_tables" route to? And secondly, what does that controller action do?

Comment: I edited my question, so you can see the routes and the purpose of the controller action

Comment: Instead of `/show_patient_tables`, why not try `/hospitalDB/show_patient_tables` as per your routes?

Comment: If I change alert to alert((this.attr("id")) I get following params:   Parameters: {"CH3"=>nil}

Comment: Hmmm - do you have a live link I could look at?

Comment: I am so sorry but no, I do not have. It seems that data is always undefined. If I alert(data) I get [object Object]

Comment: Where is your alert being called from?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41353/discussion-between-katja-and-rich-peck)